# RxSwift MVVM implemention inquire

Tags: ios, swift, mvvm, rx-swift

I have two `UITextField` and one `UITableView` in one `UIViewController`. The ViewModel of this `UIViewController` exposes one Observable to be the table view datasouce. The two `UITextField` take the parameters from users and refresh the table view Observable. `UITextField` are using `UIPickerView` as InputView and those `UIPickerViews` are using a custom class as the adapter.

In UIViewController:

```
//bind the adapter to the UIPickerView
self.viewModel.dateList.bind(to: self.datePickerView.rx.items(adapter: self.viewModel.pickerViewAdapter)).disposed(by: rx.disposeBag)
```

In ViewModel:

```
let dateList = Observable.just([[Int](0...1), [Int](1...12)])

final class PickerViewViewAdapter
    : NSObject
    , UIPickerViewDataSource
    , UIPickerViewDelegate
    , RxPickerViewDataSourceType
, SectionedViewDataSourceType {
    typealias Element = [[Int]]
    private var items: [[Int]] = []

    var activeTextField:UITextField!

    func model(at indexPath: IndexPath) throws -> Any {
        return items[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]
    }

    func numberOfComponents(in pickerView: UIPickerView) -> Int {
        return items.count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, numberOfRowsInComponent component: Int) -> Int {
        return items[component].count
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, viewForRow row: Int, forComponent component: Int, reusing view: UIView?) -> UIView {
        let label = UILabel()


        if component == 0{
            label.text = "\(2018 - items[component][row])"
        }else{
            label.text = "\(items[component][row])"
        }

        label.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .title1)
        label.textAlignment = .center
        return label
    }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, didSelectRow row: Int, inComponent component: Int){
///
/// Need to update the UITextField.text in a specific form
///
        }

    func pickerView(_ pickerView: UIPickerView, observedEvent: Event<Element>) {
        Binder(self) { (adapter, items) in
            adapter.items = items
            pickerView.reloadAllComponents()
            }.on(observedEvent)
    }
}
```

After the user select from `UIPickerView` I need to update the `UITextField.text` in a specific form, and then use those text as the parameters for the API.

**How should I do this in a Reactive way in MVVM?**

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure about what all is happening in your code, but maybe this will help out:

```
let items = Observable.just(Calendar.current.monthSymbols)
let pickerView = UIPickerView()

textField.inputView = pickerView

// this pipe displays the items in the picker view
items
    .bind(to: pickerView.rx.itemTitles) { $1 }
    .disposed(by: bag)

// this pipe displays the picked item in the text field
Observable.combineLatest(items, pickerView.rx.itemSelected) { $0[$1.row] }
    .bind(to: textField.rx.text)
    .disposed(by: bag)
```